# AWS RDS PostgreSQL connection using IAM Role is not working if dbi-resource-id specified

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm trying to give IAM User access to AWS RDS PostgreSQL with IAM credentials and got error `PAM authentication failed for user` if `DbiResourceId` specified in IAM Policy.
 1. I created the IAM policy as described [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html).

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
             "rds-db:connect"
         ],
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:rds-db:us-west-2:<My_account_id>:dbuser:<My_DbiResourceId>/readwrite_user"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

2. Created db user:

```
CREATE USER readwrite_user WITH LOGIN;
GRANT rds_iam TO readwrite_user;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_iam_test TO readwrite_user;
```

3. Try to connect

```
export PGPASSWORD="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 5432 --region $REGION --username $DBUSERNAME)"
psql -h $RDSHOST -p 5432 "dbname=database_iam_test user=$DBUSERNAME sslrootcert=./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem sslmode=verify-ca"
```

I've got error in this case:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "readwrite_user"
```

But if I use * instead of DbiResourceId — it's working!
So, this policy is working:

```
 {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
          {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [
                 "rds-db:connect"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                 "arn:aws:rds-db:us-west-2:<My_account_id>:dbuser:*/readwrite_user"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

I have only one DB resource, and I'm sure I use the correct DbiResourceId, which in my settings and returned by command:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,DbiResourceId]" --region $REGION
```

Can anybody explain why specifying `DbiResourceId` cause to error in this case?

Comment: Please notice availability of AWS Advanced JDBC Wrapper to simplify setup of IAM authentication when configuring your PostgreSQL connection to RDS: https://awslabs.github.io/aws-postgresql-jdbc/ and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the value of a DbiResourceId in the IAM Policy from DBInstancesId to the ClusterID, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify @vadim-yangunaev answer - this is the *resource_id* not the *cluster_id* which is sort of confusing. For some reason I had it in my head the documentation said cluster id when in fact it's looking for the resource id. It's obvious in hindsight but I've rarely needed to specify anything using a resource id.